# Use current Serilog ILogger instance to format a message into a string (but not print it)

Tags: c#, serilog

I have a custom `LogEntry` class that is designed for easy serialization. There are some log entries which will occur when doing an operation on an object that I want to send to the user. I also want to send those same entries to the console/whatever serilog sinks that are configured. My current approach looks like this:

```
public static void Info(this Case c, ILogger log, string message, params object[] values)
{
    log.Information(message, values);
    var formattedMessage = string.Empty; // TODO: use serilog to get the string.
                                         // This is what I'm asking for help on!
    var entry = new LogEntry
    {
        LogLevel = LogLevel.Info,
        Message = formattedMessage,
        PhaseType = c.CurrentPhase // <- it would be convenient if I could enrich
                                   //    the current serilog log with this info, 
                                   //    but I don't know how to do that either.
    };

    c.Log.Add(entry);
}
```

Where my `Case` class is a POCO ready to be sent into newtonsoft for serializing. For the sake of completeness, the `Case` class contains this definition:

```
public class Case
{
    // ...

    public List<LogEntry> Log { get; set; } = new List<LogEntry>();
}
```

Perhaps my approach is entirely wrong. Hopefully I've given enough context to explain what I'm trying to accomplish. If this question takes me down a happier path: how do I create a custom temporary sink for an `ILogger` instance?

Comment: read lots of the docs for serilog - all of these desired are addressed, but you do it more declaratively than you're thinking. To get 2 copies of events and/or messages, you wire up 2 sinks (the sink manages the formatting - you can't get the formatted version inline in your business logic as you're alluding to).

Answer (score 3):

One option is to collect the Serilog `LogEvent`s created by a logger call and use them to construct the rendered messages.

Here's an executable sketch of the general idea.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

// dotnet add package Serilog.Sinks.Console

class LogEventCollection : ILogEventEnricher
{
    // Note, this is not threadsafe
    public List<LogEvent> Events { get; } = new List<LogEvent>();

    public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory _)
    {
        Events.Add(logEvent);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        var collection = new LogEventCollection();

        // Create an `ILogger` with the collector wired in. This
        // also works with `LogContext.Push()`.
        var collected = Log.ForContext(collection);

        collected.Information("Hello");
        collected.Information("World");

        // One entry for each call above
        foreach (var evt in collection.Events)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(evt.RenderMessage(null));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[14:23:34 INF] Hello
[14:23:34 INF] World
Hello
World
```